# Find ClearCase host lists

Tags: clearcase

How can I find a list of ClearCase hosts that can be used as input to `clearmake`? I have searched for a command that can list hosts but can't find any. I have tried asking my system admin as well but have not received an answer yet. Is there any command that lets me find a list of ClearCase hosts?

Comment: > cleartool lsclients -host hostname

Comment: You should provide name of your registry server instead of 'hostname'. Read the manual: cleartool man lsclient

Comment: Ok I don't know that name either. how can I find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found there is no perfect solution that will give you a hostlist. It depends on how the workspace you have is configured. If there is an admin of your IT-services contact that person to findout what hosts are avilable.

Comment: Interesting feedback, more precise than my answer below. +1

Answer (score 0):

For "clients" (in general), the [`cleartool lsclients`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsclients.htm) command will query the ClearCase registry server host, which runs the `albd_server` process maintaining a list of current client hosts.
(It is base on the information [listed on the server in the `client_list.db` file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135901))

You need to provide the (fixed) hostname of hat registry server, in order for that command to return the list of ClearCase clients.

Note that it only list recent clients:
If a client does not access the server for 30 days, it is supposed to be dropped from the list.

That doesn't presume, however, if those ClearCase clients are fit for `clearmake`.
To my knowledge, there is no special attribute associated to a ClearCase client which distinguishes from other clients in regard to `clearmake`.

The only parameter in [`clearmake`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm) which could use an hostname would be `–B bldhost-file`.

Comment: yes that is the file that im looking to create by finding what hosts are available.